# lightest ball among 8 balls by 2 tries using a balance scales

Tags: no-computers, computer-science

I  have 8 balls and one of them is lighter than others. How could I find that ball by 2 tries? Also I have a balance scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First weight 3 vs 3. If they are the same then the light one is among the remaining 2. If they are not the same then from those 3 take 1 vs 1. I think the rest is clear.